Change "Product" string on Woocommerce checkout
I need to override the word "Product" in Woocommerce's checkout and add another one instead. I know it can be done by adding some PHP, but I couldn't find the solution after searching for it.
Please see the HTML tag for that name:

Could you please advise?

you need to overwrite this template. The template you are looking for is templates/checkout/review-order.php. How to overwrite templates - https://woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/
